# Automate slider with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider that slides images across on the click of a button using the following function

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#button a').click(function(){
    var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#myslide .cover').animate({left:-720*(parseInt(integer)-1)}) 
    $('#button a').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
        if($(this).hasClass('button'+integer)){
            $(this).addClass('active')}
    });
}); 
});
```

Is it possible to automate this using jquery?

---

Just found this oly unsure how I would go about implementing it....

```
setInterval(function() {
      // Do something every 2 seconds
 }, 2000);
```

Comment: what do you mean by automate?

Comment: so after say 3 seconds it automatically slides to the next slide

Comment: what exactly do you want to automate here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To animate the images after clicking on a button, you can use setInterval. My previous example used setTimeout, even after you mentioned setInterval. Whoops. This should be a lot cleaner.

The comments should describe what is going on.

Note that setInterval is called on button press. Every time you press the button, it will start **another instance**. The fix for this comes down to the coding logic you want to use. Try using clearInterval() if you must set this in such a way that it can be called multiple times.

```
$(function() {
    //Click our link
    $("a").click(function() {
        animateOurImage();
        setInterval(function() { animateOurImage(); }, 3000);
        //Be sure you account for the animation's duration in setInterval.
    }); 
});

function animateOurImage() {
    // We need the .each to access the image with $(this)
    $('.image').animate({
        left: "-=120" //relative to current position
    }, 1000); //Duration
}
```

Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yjhwm/

Comment: Note that if multiple .cover images animate, this would start many timers. You can either set a variable *outside* of the .animate() scope, and immediately clearTimeout(variable), followed by variable = setTimeout(). This would make only one timeout active at a time.

Alternatively, simply call the setTimeout outside of the function.

Comment: this doesnt seem to emulate the button click for some reason

Comment: Try my edits, keep in mind it may be more practical to move the animation to a new function entirely and just call the animation and setTimeout within the click event. clearTimeout() setTimeout() is probably not the cleanest way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

first, make the function which executes the animation into a first-class function (ie, give it a name and move it out of the click()):

```
function animate() {...}
```

then associate the click handler with that:

```
$('#button a').click(animate);
```

then, use setInterval() or setTimeout() to execute that function after a specified timeout:

```
setTimeout(animate, 3000);
```